# Using single nav bar on all pages, without coping it?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Is it possible to have the same nav bar on all pages, without coping and pasting the code. Basically I want to have this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

On all three pages(Home, Login, Register). Without coping and pasting the code.

Comment: You can do these by many ways like Changing your content with AJAX, You can take these view in separate php file and then you can include these in all files.

Comment: From the answers I was able to understand how to accomplish the result I want. However I don't get why my question has down vote?

Comment: Someone down voted your question, But don't worry I will up vote for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript frameworks to help you achieve this.

Javascript frameworks such as [Angular JS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) provide functionality to help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of template systems allow you to nest or inherit templates. For example, you'd put your navbar in a master template, and then simply inherit said template on all your pages.  Jade and Jinja are two that come to mind.

If you're not using any type of template system, you could still piece together HTML files with whatever language you're using, but it's going to be a bit messy.  For instance, read in multiple HTML files, concatenate them, and then serve them to the client.

Last but not least, you could dynamically add the navbar to the page, and simply include the same script on all the pages you want the navbar to appear.

Ultimately, your best option is to use a template system, as it handles things like this for you extremely efficiently and cleanly, but even without a template system you can still manage, just not as cleanly.